# JS regex pattern help wanted

Tags: regex

I'm writing a Javascript minifier in python, and I'm trying to remove comments by using a regular expression

```
\s\/\/[^\n]*\n
```

The javascript that is giving me unexpected results from the regex is

```
/* deliberately different */
// test line 1
// test line 2
var test_http = "http://test.com";
```

I'm using the great regex testing resource at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it's showing that `// test line 2` is not matched, and I don't understand why.
**NOTE**: I am deliberately looking for white-space (includes newlines) before a comment in order NOT to match declarations such as the `test_http` variable.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

Comment: ***\s\/\/[^]*\n*** , this seems to be working

Comment: Is `\/\/\s.*` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Stack - no, that matches line 1 until the last newline ([^] matches any character, including newlines).

Comment: @DeepSpace - that pattern works in this instance, but assumes comments will always have a space after the '//', which is not always the case, so I'm looking for white-space before the comment. In theory a comment could not be separated from a ';' for example, but I can use a capture group to resolve that. I just don't understand why the regex I've crafted isn't working!

Comment: What about `var test = ' // ';`…? That simplistic regex is gonna have *a lot* of false positives.

Comment: @deceze - thanks, granted it's not perfect, but it meets my needs for now. I'm seeking understanding, not perfection ;-)

Comment: @kevstev01 You can make the space optional: `^\/\/ ?.*$` Also note I used literal space and not `\s` so `\n` aren't matched and `^..$` to make sure `http://test.com` is not matched. https://regex101.com/r/pNmRPc/1 . This specific regex also doesn't match `var test = ' // ';`

Comment: @DeepSpace - Perfect, thanks, although I didn't need the start of line match. I still don't understand why my original didn't work, but at least I have a working solution. As a side issue, can you tell me how you generated the regex101 URL?

Comment: @kevstev01 Becuase your regex searches for a leading `\s` (which again, matches both space *and* `\n`). To get  a link to regex.101 you just click on "save regex" on the left side.

Comment: @DeepSpace - NOW I understand, thanks for the enlightenment. The expression I ended up with is '[\n ]\/\/[^\n]*\n', which doesn't require comment lines to be at the start of a line, but does mean that there is a potential to select variable strings containing ' //' but that does not occur in the files I'm using it on yet ;o)

Comment: that's `[\n ]\/\/[^\n]*\n`(note the space). Thanks for the regex101 tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am deliberately looking for white-space (includes newlines) before a comment in order NOT to match declarations such as the test_http variable.

If we can assume that every comment will start on a new line, then this pattern would work:

```
^(?:(?:/\*(?:.|\n)*?\*/)|(?://.*))
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UxCSa/11)

---

However, if this isn't the case you will have to invest some time in developing a context aware parser. This is because regex never were designed to be context aware. If you want to take different actions based on the context of the match, regex alone won't *(usually)* be enough.

This pattern could be used in conjunction with a context aware parser to identify comments:

```
(?:/\*(?:.|\n)*?\*/)|(?://.*)
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D2Za0n/4)

Comment: Thanks, but that pattern also matches the variable definition `var test_http = "http://test.com";`, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Regex is used to pattern match strings, and was not designed to be context aware. If you want to take different actions based on the context of the match, you will need to invest some time in developing a context aware parser.

Comment: @kevstev01 I've added a part to my answer, it might help in your specific case.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence @Olian04 - in my case all JS comments would be preceded by a new line or space, and I was handling multi-line comments as a separate regex, but thanks to your expression I've amalgamated your solution with mine and the regex I am now using is `[\n ]\/\/[^\n]*|(?:/\*(?:.|\n)*?\*/)` The comment by @DeepSpace highlighted that the regex I was using did not correctly identify the white space character search (\s) as a newline or space, so I put those characters into a specific single character list to achieve what I needed.

Comment: @kevstev01 No worries, glad i could help.